# Como evitar el la edicion con dobleclick de Mouseclicked en un jTable en java?

Tags: java

Tengo un `jTable` y quiero que al momento de dar doble click no edite la tabla ya que tengo una parte del código en la que valido que solo se le puedan ingresar números y lo hace, pero cuando le doy doble click a la tabla me permite meter letras. 
Tengo esta parte de código:

```
 private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

 if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {

     System.out.println("Se ha hecho un click");            
    }
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
        System.out.println("Se ha hecho un click");

    }

// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: No entiendo que preguntas, que se edite o no, o que solo ingresen números o que sea solo una parte de la tabla permita ser editada, se mas explicito.

Comment: Lo que quiero es validar las celdas de una columna de un jTable para que solo acepte numeros, lo que pasa que cuando le hago un click a la celda si me acepta solo numeros, pero al darle doble click me deja insertar letras

Comment: ya entiendo,y te ha servido la respuesta de @Carlos ?

Comment: no me funciono :c

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar la columna como no editable, en el momento de setear el modelo de tu tabla:

```
tbTransacciones.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {},
            new String[] {
                    "COLUMNA1", "COLUMNA2", "COLUMNA3", "COLUMNA4", "COLUMNA5"
            }) {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                Integer.class, String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class
            };
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
            boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
                false, false, false, false, false
            };
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return columnEditables[column];
            }
        });
```